# Stripe Portal Stripe Security concern

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments

I am working in the stripe portal into my website for customers to manage subscriptions.

I use my own customer id to make a call to my own database to get the stripe customer ID to start the session for the stripe redirect. My own customer id is exposed to the user and I am concerned that if an attacker can guess my own customer ids they could gain access to a clients stripe account to change subscriptions.

the HTML will contain the customer id "entity_id"

the code is something along these lines
JS

```
$(document).on("click", "#phone", function (e) {

  var entity_id = $('#entity_id').val();

  $.ajax(
    {
      type: "POST",
      url: "include_new_gun_advert/stripe_redirect.php",
      data: { entity_id },
      dataType: 'json',
      beforeSend: function () {

      },
      success: function (data) {
        view_data = data;
        console.log(view_data);

        //$("#phone").text(view_data);

       ;

      }
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');
include 'connection/pdo_conn.php';

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('MYKEY');

if(isset($_POST['entity_id']) && $_POST['entity_id'] !== '')
{
//Title 
$entity_id = $_POST['entity_id'];

try {
    $getStripeCustomerId = $connect->prepare("QUERY where entity_id = ? ");
    $getStripeCustomerId->execute([$entity_id]);
    $setStripeCustomerId = $getStripeCustomerId->fetchAll();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    $getStripeCustomerId = $e->getMessage();
}




// Authenticate your user.

$session = \Stripe\BillingPortal\Session::create([
  'customer' => $setStripeCustomerId[0][0],
  'return_url' => 'https://example.com/account',
]);

// Redirect to the customer portal.
echo json_encode( $session->url);
exit();

}

else {
  echo json_encode( 'account_payments.php');
}
```

I'm I correct to be concerned? It seems very exposed or is there safe guards?

Thanks,

Richard

Comment: Just thinking the obvious - I can keep the entity within the $_SESSION and keep it away from the user

Comment: Yes, if I knew the `entity_id` of a customer I could use this implementation to manage their subscriptions. You probably need to implement an actual authentication solution here, where the customer has to login and you set cookies in their browser or so on, and tie that it into the backend code for `stripe_redirect.php`. No association, but something like UserFrosting maybe.